# Is this a virus? C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\FyNtEw.exe

Tags: windows-11, popups

Rfter updating my computer Windows 11 & restarted the system, the following warning popups again and again:
"Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your computer?"

```
(CMD logo here) Windows Command Processor
Programme location: "C\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k START""
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\FyNtEw.exe" & EXIT
```

Even if I clicked on No and Yes, it pops back up again and again. Any help?

See the picture below I took from my phone

[image]

Comment: If you already clicked Yes, and it really is malicious, you are basically pwned. You'll want to restore to a previous known-good backup.

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR REPLY. If i would not click YES ....clicking NO would not go away, thatsa why I clicked YES. but it pops ups again and a gains I can not see my desktop screen.... after some time... itwas gone. Thanks .. it seems I have to clean install my OS.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you where the file is.  It's probably a **malware**.  If it wasn't malware or virus, it wouldn't have an obscure name.  Go to that path and delete it.

If it won't let you delete it then rename it to `FyNtEw.txt` so it cant get executed and then reboot your PC.

And then install a virus or malware scanner.

Comment: @Leonidas - You can also upload the executable to something like VirusTotal and it will likely tell you if it's malicious. Of course I agree, it's likely malicious, due to the fact there is an AutoRuns entry for the executable and you clearly do not recognize it.

Comment: Yes I can delete it easily now...I think that command might hvae created another malware chains in some other places...so I may be haapy to be able to delete the first malware command exe file. anyway thanks

Comment: @Ramhound - yes it is a good advice. Thanks. it seems I have to clean install my OS.